# Media Queries for desktop screens and mobile screen

Tags: css, media-queries

I have this media query:

```
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px),

only screen
and (max-device-width : 320px)
and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 2),

only screen
and (max-device-width : 320px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2),

only screen
and (max-device-width : 320px) {
```

It selects browsers on a  desktop less than 320px in width, iphone 4's in portrait but it also selects iphone 4's in landscape. Surely this should NOT select iPhone 4's in landscape?

From my understanding the first part selects screens less than 320px in width.

Second part same as second but with webkit vendor prefix

Third part selects screens on mobile devices less than 320px in width but with double pixel density (iPhone 4/4s in this case)

and fourth part is same as previous two but without double pixel density therefore should select iPhone 3gs and other mobiel devices which have 320px max width screens. I therefore, based on the above do not expect it to select landscape mode on any iPhone?

Any ideas how to add to it to solve that?

Neil

Comment: you're much more likely to get useful answers when addressing specific issues, and after showing some research effort. please refer to the [stackoverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), for more information on the expected format for posted questions here, and revise your question accordingly. welcome aboard, by the way

Comment: It is a specific issue, the media query is selecting the iPhone in landscape when I expect it not to be. I wrote the media query myself and this is the issue I am facing. thus my question above.  The second part was merely an associated question. I know of two ways to accomplish it and understand their positives and negatives but would like other peoples thoughts, surely there is nothing wrong with that? Neil

Comment: nothing wrong, i was merely stating that you should split this into two questions, and elaborate on what you have tried so far

Comment: Updated question and will post the secondary part now separatley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `orientation : landscape` to your CSS, like this:

```css
@media only screen
and (max-device-width : 320px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Ok, so does the iPhone still report its width as 320px even when it's in landscape?  If so then it makes sense to have to use the orientation option

Comment: I think `orientation` is made for mobile devices. You can't use it on your computer monitor, because there is no portrait orientation!

Comment: My advice is to try the CSS with iPhone.